# Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x^TAx \geq 0$. Prove that $\ker(A) = \ker(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x^TAx \geq 0$. Prove that $\ker(A) = \ker(A^T)$.

My idea:
if we can prove $A$ is symmetric, then we can solve it?

Comment: We do not have enough information to deduce that $A$ is symmetric. For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}.
$$

Comment: You can write $A = P + S,$  where $P$ is symmetric positive semidefinite and $S$ is skew symmetric, that is $S^T = -S.$ If $v$ is a column vector and $Av = 0$ but $Pv \neq 0,$ what does that say?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \in \ker A$ or $x \in \ker A^T$. Then we have

$$x^T\frac{A + A^T}{2}x = x^T A x = 0 \tag 1$$

(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307381/why-do-we-assume-that-a-matrix-in-quadratic-form-is-symmetric) for the first equality.)

This implies

$$\frac{A + A^T}{2}x = 0 \tag 2$$

so that

$$(A + A^T)x = 0 \tag 3$$

where  $(2)$ follows since $\frac{A + A^T}{2}$ is symmetric positive semidefinite (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374771/show-that-if-langle-x-ax-rangle-0-then-ax-0)).

Thus if $x \in \ker A$ $(3)$ gives $A^Tx = 0$ and vice versa so that $\ker A = \ker A^T$.

$\square$

Comment: Yes. With (1) you easily prove the rest but you did not prove (1). You provided a link with a lemma.